# Issue in SSRS Tablix property

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-2012, ssrs-tablix

In SSRS Report i want to space b/w the cells in table(Tablix). 
In Html called cell-spacing use in tables, but i have no idea to in SSRS report to insert space b/w cells.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simulate this effect using:

- `BorderStyle`: `Double`
- `BorderWidth`: `3pt` or more